# Conditions to guarantee nowhere-dense subsets of open sets in a topological measure space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose I have a topological measure space $X$ that has the property below -- assume that the measure on $X$ is compatible with its topology.

> Every open $U \subset X$ has a nowhere-dense subset $M \subset U$ such that $\mu(M) > 0$.

1. What equivalent conditions could I impose on $X$ to guarantee that it has this property? For example, in terms of separation axioms, I suspect that $X$ would have to be completely normal, but I know that's not sufficient.

Let's say that I'd also like to specify that $X$ is second-countable.

2. Is it redundant to specify that $X$ is secound-countable?
3. If $X$ satisfies the given property, am I automatically constrained to have $X$ locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$? What if $X$ is also second-countable?

Comment: No to 3. of course (in many manifolds this holds). Second countable is not needed, but "nice to have". Try to see what you need to make Cantor sets of positive measure.

Comment: Sure, I suppose I should've asked if I'm confined to finite-dimensional spaces and/or things that don't have local homeomorphisms to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: And yes, totally! So, Brouwer's theorem gives us a characterization of Cantor spaces (perfect, compact, non-empty, metrizable, totally disconnected), which I'm not sure tells me much about some space $X$ that I'd embed it in/measure that I'd use on it; conversely, if I try to construct it like I would in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I think I'd only be using completeness and the fact that every subset of $X$ contains some set of arbitrarily small measure -- are these really the only things I'd need? And what kinds of topological spaces allow that to happen?

Comment: We can define a measure $\mu$ with the given property on any separable space $X$ without isolated points.  Indeed, let $D=\{d_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a dense subset of $X$. For each $A\subset X$ put $\mu(A)=\sum\{2^{-n}:d_n\in A\}$.